# Work order data need to be stored in SalesForce databse

Tags: database

I need to save custom data(Work order related data) into sales force database. I need to have a service for this the same will be called in my SOA application. What database API i have to use to store my data into Salesforce database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in standard Rest services from salesforce to create records in salesforce. These services has support for CRUD operations.
You can follow below document.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm